# Why Mockbean mockito not work in new thread

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, mockito, junit4, spring-test

I found that Mockbean is work the test main thread, but not work in the new thread call, following is my demo code.  call the mock first time in new thread is work, but when call the demoService in second times, it return null (mock not work)

##Reference Jar Version
mockito-core 4.11.0
JDK1.8
Junit4
SpringBoot: 1.5.22.RELEASE

```
/***
 * demo test case for find why mockito mock not work in new thread
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoApplication.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    protected DemoService demoService;


    /**
     * call the mock in main thread, the mock all work
     */
    @Test
    public void testNormalCase_work() {

        DemoServiceMock.mockdoSomething(demoService);

        String result = demoService.doSomething("324234");
        System.out.println("return: " + result);

        String result2 = demoService.doSomething("324234");
        System.out.println("return2: " + result);
    }


    /***
     * call the mock in new thread
     * When call the demoService in second times, it return null (mock not work)
     */
    @Test
    public void testInNewThread_notWork() {

        DemoServiceMock.mockdoSomething(demoService);


        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //for the first time call, the mock is work
                String result = demoService.doSomething("324234");
                System.out.println("return in thread: " + result);

                //for this second time call in new thread, the mock not work and return null
                String result2 = demoService.doSomething("324234");
                System.out.println("return2 in thread: " + result2);

            }
        });

        t.start();

    }


}

public class DemoServiceMock {

    public static void mockdoSomething(DemoService demoService){

        Mockito.doReturn("mockReturnValue").when(demoService).doSomething(any());

    }
}
```

I found that Mockbean is work the test main thread, but not work in the new thread call, following is my demo code.  call the mock first time in new thread is work, but when call the demoService in second times, it return null (mock not work)

##Reference Jar Version
mockito-core 4.11.0
JDK1.8
Junit4
SpringBoot: 1.5.22.RELEASE

Comment: You mistakenly copied the first paragraph to the bottom of your question. Did you want to add more information? If so, please edit to add the information which is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your behavior locally (with JUnit 5, Spring Boot 2, and JDK 11 though).
Nevertheless, it is very fishy that you do not wait for your thread to complete. Running the test multiple times could succeed or fail, depending on the order of execution of your statements.

By the time the second call is made, the test runner has probably shut down and deregistered any stubbing calls. A prime example of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Waiting for the thread to complete would likely "solve" your problem:

```
@Test
public void testInNewThread_notWork() {
    DemoServiceMock.mockdoSomething(demoService);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //for the first time call, the mock is work
            String result = demoService.doSomething("324234");
            System.out.println("return in thread: " + result);

            //for this second time call in new thread, the mock not work and return null
            String result2 = demoService.doSomething("324234");
            System.out.println("return2 in thread: " + result2);

        }
    });

    t.start();
    t.join(); // wait for thread to complete execution!
}
```

PS do yourself a favor and stop using obsolete/end-of-life software and library. There's JUnit 5, Spring Boot 3, and JDK 17. All of the latter still get updates and security fixes, while your versions remain unmaintained and vulnerable.

Comment: Yes, I found if I use Junit5 and Spring 2.7.12, the issue is fix.

Comment: @stonez08 did you try `t.join()` with older versions of the library and framework? Does that line fix it then?

Comment: But If I could't upgrade my spring and junit version , how to slove this issue?

Comment: @stonez08 once again: did you try `t.join()`, as suggested twice already?